# How to call methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few js files in my project with this structure:

```
(function (window, $) {
    var reload = function (force) { /* implementation here */ };
    //more variables are here, the same construction as above
})(this, $);
```

Are more such files, for each part (page) of the website there is one js with this structure to manage the page. The whole site is a single page, with those js files managing DOM nodes by hiding, showing and filling content and this gives to the user the illusion s/he navigates throw multiple pages.

1. I'd like to get a simple explication about how the above construction is loaded - I see the head.js library that loads all those js scripts, but I don't understand where is loaded, how to access it.
2. I'd like to know how to access by myself the specific reload() I need. As I told you, are more js files with the same structure (resources.js, users.js, reports.js etc). How do I access the reload function inside, let's say, reports.js on a button press in the html I load all those scripts?

Comment: The JS function that you show above is self-executed once when the JS file is loaded. Hard to help you without more information.

Comment: This is a very open question, related to architecture of javascript in applications. I would suggest reading about javascript modules and namespaces. Search for "module pattern". See "revealing module pattern" here http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/#module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a self-invoked function, which is a good practice in order to avoid reusing variable identifiers and break third-party code.

Another point is variables declared inside the self-invoked function are available in the scope of the function body nor in the global scope. This is nice too, since the "garbage" created during your scripts can be collected when the function ends (ok, not always if you use them in a *clousure*).

Also, since you declare such variables in the function scope, other libraries doing stuff in their own "self-invoked function scope" would use variable and function identifiers like yours, but it'll be no problem, as both are different scopes!

```
function (window, $)
```

In the case of the above signature, the self-invoked function has two input parameters:

- *window* will hold the JavaScript browser's Window object.
- *$* will hold a shortcut object or function (usually, jQuery).

Declaring such input parameters you avoid a lot of problems, because one could reuse the `window` identifier and store another object, but inside your self-invoked function scope, `window` will hold the `Window` object anyway becuase it's a different reference.

> How do I access the reload function inside, let's say, reports.js on a
>   button press in the html I load all those scripts?

You're declaring a local variable storing the whole `reload()` function. In order to have access to it in any scope, you need to declare it in the *global scope*:

```
var reload = null;

(function (window, $) {
    // Setting the variable living in the global scope!
    reload = function (force) { /* implementation here */ };

    //more variables are here, the same construction as above

})(this, $);
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering just that snippet of code, the answer to #2 is: you can't access `reload` from the outside. It's declared as a local variable to the "immediately invoked function expression", a function that is called as soon as it's defined (which answers #1, I hope).

Usually, thats is used to create modules that will expose some methods and properties. For example, if the code were:

```
var obj = (function (window, $) {

    var reload = function (force) { /* implementation here */ };

    return {
        reload : reload
    };

})(this, $);
```

Then you could invoke `realod` with

```
obj.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access these variables unless you modify these .js files.

```
(function (window, $) {

    var reload = function (force) { /* implementation here */ };

    //more variables are here, the same construction as above

    window.reload = reload;

})(this, $);
```

The code above makes the variable/method `reload` available from outside of the code.